# Script to create line chart based on dates with values

Tags: python, linux

I have a text file with 2 lines. One line represent value and the other date of value. I would like to create line chart . I need to use file as a source for data.
Data format looks lie:
Line 1: 4 5 6 7 8
Line 2: 12/03/2012  13/03/2012 14/03/2012 15/03/2012  16/03/2012

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Reading data, finding a charting library? What did you try so far?

Comment: Where does the string `work_04.11.13_23:59` come from that you try to convert to a float?

Comment: Sorry. it should be date. I just what to know how to create simple chart where x=dates and y=values.

Comment: make sure the data points are sorted wrt. the x-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `float` from a datetime string. First, you need to parse the formatted dates to objects of type `datetime.datetime`, or `datetime.date`, e.g., using [datetime.datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Then you can plot it easily using matplotlib. Just have a look at the examples in the documentation.

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
- http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html
- http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html

Answer (score 1):

Why you not use line-chart of [Pygal](http://pygal.org/chart_types/#line-charts). See a sample code [here](http://pygal.org/chart_types/#line-charts)

Edit 1: Just saw your update. If you see error carefully, you would see message `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '04.11.13'`

You are trying to convert string in date-format to float which is throwing error.

You can go through http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html and http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html to see the usage of dates in matplotlib.

Comment: I want it as an image and not for a web site.